# Android Switch xml textOn string resource

Tags: android, android-widget, android-switch

Is there a way to specify a resource id in XML for a Switch? When I do the following I get random integers which I'm assuming are the id itself and not the resolved String?

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/toggle_widget_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
    android:textOn="@string/on"
    android:textOff="@string/off" />
```